# LNK1181 error converting from VS 2008 to VS 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, linker-errors

I have a C++ DLL in VS2008 that I am trying to convert to VS2012.  Windows 7 64 bit, but compiling for 32 bit application.

I am getting the following linker error:

```
1>  Debug_Win32\XYZ.obj
1>  Debug_Win32\ABC.obj 
1>  
1>  Starting pass 1
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file ',0.obj'
```

I don't have a file named ",0" in the project, so I'm confused as to where that is coming from.

I've done some searching and tried all the various fixes I've seen (repairing VS 2012, deleting all the build output directories, deleting Microsoft.Cpp.X32.user file, etc.), but no luck.

Any idea what causes this or how I could try and debug it?

EDIT:  Had subsystem flag set to "Not set", changing it worked great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't have a file named ",0" in the project, so I'm confused as to where that is coming from.

It comes from the linker's /SUBSYSTEM option.  Which is more explicit in VS2012, it it no longer supports XP by default so gets explicit about the sub-system version number.  `6,0` for modern Windows versions, that's where `,0` came from.

Right-click your project, Properties, Linker, System.  You *must* change the SubSystem setting, it cannot be "Not Set" or blank.  Pick either "Console" for a console mode app, "Windows" for a GUI app or DLL.